# Построчное чтение из файла

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно считать файл. Проблема в том что при использовании

```
QString helpfulStr = File.readLine();
```

вместо русских букв считается кракозябра, а при использовании

```
QTextStream textStream(&file);
QString helpfulStr = textStream.readLine();
```

потеряется переход на новую строку в файле. И последующие

```
helpfulStr = textStream.readLine();
```

будут возвращать пустоту.

Comment: А такой вариант не пойдет: QTextStream input(&file);
input.setCodec("UTF-8"); input.readLine();

Comment: Как переводить на новую строку?

Comment: Можно прочитать все разом: QTextStream input(&file); input.setCodec("UTF-8"); QString str = input.readAll();

Comment: Этот вариант мне не подходит. Мне нужно именно построчное чтение, поскольку парсить полученные данные потом будет очень проблематично.

Comment: QTextStream input(&file); input.setCodec("UTF-8"); input.readLine(); не подходит - не переводит на новую строку, вместо русских букв кракозябры. По умолчанию, я так понял, текстовый поток сам находит нужный кодек.

Comment: `QTextStream input(&file); input.setCodec("UTF-8"); while(input) { str = readLine(); }` И складывать строки например в QStringList

Comment: Говорю же - не работает так как нужно. Не читает последующие строки, да и вместо русских символов кракозябры.

Comment: Проверьте отрываете ли Вы файл с флагами `QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text` или нет? Может проблема в этом.

Answer (score 1):

В общем дело обстоит так: при открытии текстового потока курсор в читаемом файле переходит в конец. Я же передавал в функцию ссылку на открытый файл, в функции создавал поток и поэтому последующие строки из других функций не открывались. Решение: создавать поток при открытии файла, передавать в функции сам поток.